# How to rebuild Full Text indexes after MSSQL upgrade from 2014 to 2017

Tags: sql-server-2016, full-text-search

When I updated from 2014 to 2017 I chose the option to migrate Full-Text Indexes instead of rebuild them during the update.  The update went well, and I'd like to repopulate those indexes now, but I'm not clear about how to initiate that. I rebuilt the *catalog* but that went super fast.  Do I need to open properties of the Full-Text index of each table where it's enabled and tell each to repopulate?

Answer (score 1):

You can start population of full-text indexes using T-SQL, as outlined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/populate-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#example---run-a-full-population-on-a-table):

```sql
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON Production.Document  
   START FULL POPULATION;
```

If you want to do this for every full text index in the database, you can run a query like this to generate the script for every full-text index. The output from the below query can be copied into a new query window & run to start full population on every full-text index in the database:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(N'ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON ',
              QUOTENAME(s.name),
              '.',
              QUOTENAME(o.name),
              N' START FULL POPULATION;'
              )
from sys.fulltext_indexes AS fti
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.object_id = fti.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id;
```